# Necessary setup for a full computer

Tags: purchasing

The standard Raspberry Pi, $35 version, seems to come without any cables.  Assuming standard plugs are available, what cables and devices will be needed to use the device in a mouse-click graphical interface with internet connection?

Comment: I would think this would somewhat subjective. As people's idea of a _normal computer_ differs.

Comment: your question is a bit broad, for instance you need a SD card, HDMI/VGA cable, Monitor/TV with VGA/HDMI/DVI connector, network cable, usb keyboard/mouse etc... all of which has a localised cost

Comment: Well the suggested OS is a graphical system, right?  I think the cost part is subjective, and the rest could be made non-subjective, although I might need to edit the question a bit.

Comment: This is answered in the [Quick Start Guide](http://www.raspberrypi.org/quick-start-guide) and may not be a good question for the site.

Answer (score 6):

You will probably need (it is not the bare minimum but in order for it to be usable as a PC):

- An SD card (Class 4 / 4 GB works fine)
- A HDMI cable to connect to display
- A USB keyboard
- An USB mouse (or not)
- A power supply (in some cases your mobile phone/tablet charger will do, since it uses a standard Micro-USB connector)
- USB-Micro USB cable for power
- Network cable to connect to your router / USB Wi-Fi dongle

If you plan to attach external storage such as USB hard drives, you will probably need a powered USB hub as well, since disks tend to drain a lot of power from USB (and there are only two ports on Raspberry Pi)

Comment: From experience, 2GB SD also works fine.

Comment: True, but then your additional software choices will be very limited.

Comment: I have everything that I need installed in Arch.

Comment: How about Eclipse or OpenOffice.org? You would quickly run out :)

Comment: If I want to run any intensive applications then I use X11 forwarding from my main rig. I bet they run horribly on the Pi!

Answer (score 1):

At the very least you need:

- Micro USB Power Cable
- Network connection (Ethernet)
- SD Card (4GB suggested, 2GB possible)

This setup will allow you to install an Operating System, ssh into the box and configure it.

If you want a display you will also need a HDMI cable and monitor.